# How to call an http method without the observable in Angular 2

Tags: angular

When I call this function the console.log() works, but the http.delete method never runs, I assume because I haven't subscribed to the observable.

Because I'm calling this from a button on a form, I don't care about returning anything so is there a way to just make the call?

```
  deleteCompany(id) { 
      console.log('from data service: ', id);
      this.http.delete(this.url + 'Companies/' + id + '?' + this.token).map(res => res.json());
   }
```

**Edit:**
I went with this instead. Is this the correct way to handle this?

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
...
return this.http.delete(this.url + 'Companies/' + id + '?' + this.token).toPromise();
```

Comment: "Edit:" looks fine. You can also call `subscribe()` without passing a callback. I think this makes it more obvious what the intent is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Gunter pointed out, you need to call `subscribe` if you want to use observable. You can convert `observable` to `promise` if you want something to be returned(as promises are not lazy) as following :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
     deleteCompany(id) { 
          console.log('from data service: ', id);
         return this.http.delete(this.url + 'Companies/' + id + '?' + this.token).toPromise();
       }
```

In order to consume it use `then` instead of `subscribe` in your component. e.g :

```
this._yourServiceName.deleteCompany(this._id).then((data)=> console.log(data), (err) => console.log("error occured", err););
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To ensure I understand (I'm very new at this), in your example you're mapping the response so that I have something to consume in my component and then using .promise to actually trigger the http call correct? So how does 'return' fit into this since I noticed you didn't use it?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to return the observable(edited now). Generally, we use `map` (or any other method) to transform the data stream. Using `map(res => res.json()` will parse the response as JSON which we need not use here. `toPromise`  method is going return a promise which gets resolved using `then` method in component.

Answer (score 2):

No. Observables are lazy and won't do anything before `subscribe` or `toPromise` is called.